# Remove elements from array. index. C#. List<double>

Tags: c#, arrays, list, indexing

I need your help. It's easy question, I think.
So. I work in C# with array.

```
var TinArr = new List<double>();
```

Next I have some elements in it. For example:

```
TinArr[0]=0.5;
TinArr[1]=0.6;
TinArr[2]=1.1;
TinArr[3]=1.5;
```

Ok. Then I have cycle for remove some of them:

```
for (var j = 0; j < TinArr.Count; j++)
  {
     if (TinArr[j] <= 1)
     {
        TinArr.RemoveAt(j);
      }
   }
```

As I understand, when I'll remove element with index "0", next element with index "1" after this action will have index "0". Maybe I'm wrong. How can I save index? Or maybe I should start cycle from the beginning? **NEED YOU HELP! THANKS!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
TinArr.RemoveAll(x => x <= 1);
```

But if using a `for`-loop is a requirement, you should start from the end:

```
for (var j = TinArr.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    if (TinArr[j] <= 1)
    {
        TinArr.RemoveAt(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I forgot about it! Thank you, I will try it right now. "x" - index?

Comment: @Maria The `x` in the lambda expression represents the item in the list that you're testing to determine if you need to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in reverse rather, something like

```
for (var j =TinArr.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
 if (TinArr[j] <= 1)
 {
    TinArr.RemoveAt(j);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it yourself, only missing post-decrement:

```
for (var j = 0; j < TinArr.Count; j++)
    if (TinArr[j] <= 1)
        TinArr.RemoveAt(j--);
```